# ANT+ SDK - requestAccess faild (Other failure)

Tags: android, permissions

I'm trying to develop own Android application using ANT+ sensors.
My app is based on ([developer's Sampler code and SDK](https://github.com/ant-wireless/ANT-Android-SDKs)).
However I found the strange thing during tests. I mean when I start to searching devices I immediately receive a message:

> W/AntPluginPcc: BBD30600: RequestAccess failed: OTHER_FAILURE

At first I suppose that a reason of this problem is that I have a phone with Marshmallow OS (instead my wife's phone is based on Lollipop OS and all works fine). I tried to find anything in documentation related this but didn't find anything interesting. I add to Manifest some permissions (I mean com.dsi.ant.permission.ANT, android.permission.BLUETOOTH etc.) and set the permissions in code, but it doesn't help to me to solve my issue.

May be anybody received this problem and may be somebody solve it. Could you please share your solution to me?

P.S. I install the ANT+ Plugin services, ANT Radio Service. in App I use the ANT+ SDK from github. May be I should use also the ANT SDK? (I want to connect to HRM and cycle devices which use ANT+ protocol)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same problem as I you need to realize the `AntRadioServiceConnection` class.

I found it [here](https://github.com/ant-wireless/ANT-Android-SDKs/tree/master/ANT_Android_SDK/Sample_Applications/Sample_BackgroundScan/Source/src/com/dsi/ant/sample/backgroundscan).

And you should be sure that you have all services and plugins installed on your phone.